# Is there some samples of integration between Nativescript and new angular 2 router?

Tags: mobile, angular, native, nativescript

I recently update my nativescript + angular 2 project. Since this date, the project can't no longer generate app.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest RC3 and future updates you can take a look at the '[nativescript-ui-samples-angular](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular)' repo.

It contains examples of the [nativescript-telerik-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui) components plus it is a full angular 2 {N} project. This means that the navigations etc. are all implemented using angular 2 mechanisms. You can see the way the app handles its navigation in the '[sdkAngular/app/navigation](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/release/sdkAngular/app/navigation)' where you can find the ***app.routes.ts*** which lists all of the possible routes in the application (with the current angular RC3 APIs) and for example one of the [Components](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/navigation/examples-list/examples-list.component.ts#L24-L29) which handles the navigation with the use of the **ActivatedRoute**.